# Haskell: refer to type of value at compile time

Tags: haskell, types, vinyl

I'm wondering if there's a nice way to refer to types of values without explicitly aliasing them using `type` in code (not at runtime - there is no reification going on here).

Take the following code (using [Data.Vinyl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.2)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Vinyl

name = Field :: "name" ::: String
age = Field :: "age" ::: Int
type Person = ["name" ::: String, "age" ::: Int]
```

Here we have the types `"name" ::: String` and `"age" ::: Int` repeated in two places. If we reuse fields in multiple records, this can become multiple places. Despite the fact that the `Person` type is really *referring* to the constituent fields, the type declarations are independent. So changing `age` to be represented by `Float`, say, requires changes in various places.

Obviously it's not necessary to explicitly type things, since they will be inferred. However, in my case the record types are being returned from an options parser, and thus exported. Likewise, one could write the following:

```
type Name = "name" ::: String
name = Field :: Name
type Age = "age" ::: Int
age = Field :: Age
type Person = [Name, Age]
```

However, this then involves another load of type aliases and double the number of lines. What I would *like* to be able to write is the following:

```
name = Field :: "name" ::: String
age = Field :: "age" ::: Int
type Person = [typeof name, typeof age]
```

This explicitly links the type of a `Person` to the types of its fields.

Is there a way (preferably sans-TH, but I'd be interested even involving TH) to do this?

Comment: To be honest, I kind of prefer the first version with the aliases to the second one with the typeof. You even have a neat naming convention already (fields in lowercase and types capitalized)

Comment: What's wrong with Template Haskell? That's a nice way to solve your problem. I don't know the Vinyl view of the world, but `lens` sems to suit: https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy enough to make a `String -> [Name] -> DecsQ` function out of
the following. Too bad with ghc7.6 (at least), the check for cycles in type
synonyms seems to stop the prettier `type Person = $(listOfT ['name, 'age])` from
working out.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Vinyl

name = Field :: "name" ::: String
age = Field :: "age" ::: Int

let listOfT (n:ns) = do
        VarI _ ty _ _ <- reify n
        (appT promotedConsT) (return ty) `appT` listOfT ns
    listOfT [] = promotedNilT
 in return <$> tySynD (mkName "Person") [] (listOfT ['name, 'age])
```